# jQgrid bindkeys not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use jqgrid 4.5.2. and want to implement keyboard navigation.

I create my grid with these options:

```
$('#shipTable').jqGrid({ 
    data : griddata ,
    autowidth : true ,
    datatype : 'local' ,
    scrollOffset : 23 ,
    colNames : headers ,
    colModel : colModel ,
    rowNum : len ,
    sortorder : 'desc' ,
    sortname : 'id' ,
    ignoreCase : true ,
    scrollrows : true ,
    viewrecords : true ,
    gridview : true ,
    multiselect : true,
    multiboxonly : false ,
    caption : "a caption"
});

$('#shipTable').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    pager : '#pager'
});

$('#shipTable').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
    del : false ,
    add : false ,
    edit : true ,
    search : true
});

$('#shipTable').jqGrid('bindKeys', {
    onEnter : function(rowid){
        alert("You enter a row with id:" + rowid);
    } ,
    onSpace : null ,
    onLeftKey : null ,
    onRightKey : null ,
    scrollingRows : true
});
```

The grid is constructed fine, using the up down arrows just scrolls the overflowed view. If the view is not overflowed, nothing happens. Pressing enter when a row is selected also yields no alert.

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score -3):

You need to add

```
$('#shipTable').jqGrid('bindKeys');
```

see the [Bind Keys](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method here  for more information

Comment: the tagid is actually #shipTable, excuse my typo.